# Bluemix - how to deploy Insights for Twitter application

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy an application, with only the service Insights for Twitter, but when I launch the command "cf push xxx" the system return me this error:
"Could not find service Insights for Twitter-zo to bind to xxx".

Could someone give me any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you go to your Bluemix dashboard, do you see a service with that name? and Is it binded to your app?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the service prior to run the `cf push` command.

You can create the service in the UI (look for the `Insights for Twitter` service in the Catalog under "Data and Analytics"). Make sure the name of the service matches what you have defined in your manifest.yml file, in this case it should be "Insights for Twitter-zo".

Or you can create it via cli with `cf create-service` command:

`$ cf create-service twitterinsights Free "Insights for Twitter-zo"`